# How to discover local network resources on windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, service-discovery

I'm trying to find a way of automatically discovering and communicating with a local network service running on desktop/laptop.  Much like the Zune's wifi sync feature.
iPhone can do this using Bonjour service.  Is there anything like that on WP7 platform?  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently nothing like this available in the SDK.

Network operations are currently very limited and you're restricted to HTTP based connections. I'm not sure how useful that would be for the scenario you describe.